# Retrieve admin password on Orchard 1.8

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I forgot my Orchard admin password, so I googled around on how to (manually) reset it. I found [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/04/28/recovering-the-admin-password-in-orchard.aspx) article on how to achieve this.

So I went to my server, opened the website in WebMatrix, opened the database, set a new password and the PasswordFormat to **Clear**. I opened the site and tried to login, but still it said that the UserName and/or password was incorrect.

Has anyone ever got a similar issue? Any thoughts on why it doesn't work?

I am using Orchard 1.8 and WebMatrix 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. If anyone else runs into this issue here is wat was the problem:

In Orchard 1.8 information is also stored as XML in the table [Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord](http://orcharddojo.net/orchard-resources/Library/Wiki/InfosetPart). By editing the rows ALSO in here, the effects take place and the password can be reset!

Comment: What information do you edit?! I've got over 700 rows of data in mine?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign Bertrand has updated his blogpost, see https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/recovering-the-admin-password-in-orchard

Answer (score 0):

I had access to another user and access to the database which I edited and replaced the admin user's hash and salt with the user I knew the password to , could then log in with that password.